# Changing Img Src to parent A href Using CSS

Tags: html, image, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to change the `img` element to its parent `a` tag's `href` attribute? For example, if I have:

```
<a class="img-parent" href="http://placehold.it/400x200">
    <img class="img-class" src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt="This will change" />
</a>
```

Can I change the content of the `img` using **only** CSS?

I know for a fact that I can change the `img` using the following code, but can I just point it to the parent's `href` attribute?

```
.img-class{
   content:url("http://placehold.it/400x200");
}
```

Comment: Nope not possible, as far as i know.

Comment: I think content:url is only used with the :before and :after pseudo-elements is CSS

Comment: @AndrewAshton Suprisingly it works

Comment: @ISuthanBala It depends what browser you're viewing it in; appears to work in Chrome but not Firefox.

Comment: Anyhow I don't think it's possible to accomplish this with CSS, you would need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Are you trying to use only css, or can you use Sass or Less, which eventually compile into css?

Comment: @Abhi I am using Less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, I think you could use [CSS variables](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1):

```css
.img-parent {
  --img: attr(href);
}
.img-class {
  content: url(var(--img));
}
```

But don't expect it to work (yet):

- `content` applying to all elements (and not only `::before` and `::after`) is not widely implemented.
- `attr()` in properties other than `content` is not widely implemented.
- CSS variables are not widely implemented.
- CSS variables inside `url()` are even less implemented.